# How do you count lines using word-wrap: break-word?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to know how many lines there are inside a div without line breaks but "word-wrap: break-word" only?

How would I know the total number of lines inside of this div?

```
<div id="content_text" style="word-wrap: break-word; background: red; color: white; width: 100px;">dsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdasdsadasdas</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a copy of an element, put just one character there and get the height, being the height of one line:

```js
function getLineHeight(element) {
    const copy = element.cloneNode();
    copy.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    copy.style.position = 'absolute';
    copy.textContent = 'a';
    element.parentNode.appendChild(copy);

    const lineHeight = copy.offsetHeight;

    lineHeight.remove();

    return lineHeight;
}
```

Then, you can get the lines count as follows:

```js
const linesCount = Math.round(element.offsetHeight / getLineHeight(element));
```

I hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Not that easy I would think