# react How do I get the number of lines of text wrapped within an element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We are using react.
The div has been styled with wordWrap: "break-word", so the text will be wrapped.
I want to get how many lines of text are wrapped without elements.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const text =
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "150px",
          textOverflow: "ellipsis",
          overflow: "hidden",
          wordWrap: "break-word"
        }}
      >
        <p>
          {text.split("\n").map((text, i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i}>
              {text}
              <br />
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you count lines using word-wrap: break-word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352400/how-do-you-count-lines-using-word-wrap-break-word)

Comment: I don't want to copy it and display it on the screen.
I only want to get the number of lines.

Comment: The number of lines depends on screen resolution, browser settings, zoom, even extensions used. You cant get the exact number of lines without rendering it first.